# does my question focused or still not?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Software Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Tips on converting UBER app for waste management app](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/433009/tips-on-converting-uber-app-for-waste-management-app)

So I asked here to have some comment about the needs for reopening the question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry to say this, but I don't think this question has a chance to get reopened, since it is way too vague and way too broad for the Q&A format of this site (please read [this older meta post](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6490#6490)  about what our community perceives as too broad). Such kind of questions simply don't work here. I would expect Quora to be the better place to ask the question (but even they seem to have issues with the way you stated the question there).

- The question for "tips" in the title is a poll for a list-of-things, which we do not process here (see former link).
- The question for cost or effort would require an in-depth requirements analysis of the problem and its surrounding conditions, together with the knowledge of the level of expertise on your side (and even then we could be heavily wrong on this). This is not answerable by "outsiders" like us.
- The "update" does not even contain a clear question statement. I am under the impression you are looking for a discussion, but the SE sites are no discussion boards, they are Q&A sites with a focus on specific, answerable questions. If, however, you are looking for specific programming help for that topic, you need to ask on Stackoverflow. For this, your question needs to include the relevant code sections you tried to implement by yourself, and tell what does not work as intended, and where specificially you need help.

I would recommend to dig yourself through the links given at our [on-topic page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), especially the ones in the paragraph *"Before asking a question"* and make yourself more familiar about which kind of questions work on this site. That should give you more background about the questions which are suitable here.